# What does sustained growth mean?

Tags: macroeconomics

In the Overlapping Generations model, it’s stated that sustained growth is not possible in a absence of technical progress.

Answer (score 1):

By sustained growth means growth that can be sustained in the long-run. In standard OG model if there is no technological progress there can be only short-run “spur” of growth if people save more but it is not possible to actually have sustained growth in the long-run.

Comment: Thanks! And what’s the equation that proves it?

Comment: @tryingtogetsmth That can be proven by solving the model. Solution to the growth path of standard OG model will be such that it depends on technology